# passing in a guid to an API request

Tags: cypress

Ran into an interesting issue when attempting to create a cypress API request for the following GET account by ID API
The GET API ends with the following: ...v9.1/accounts(guid)
I have not been able to determine how to add the parentheses to my variable:
accounts' `${acctId}` This results in an error and runon: accountsguid I tried adding an + and  escaping the parenthesis like (, but am not able to get it to work. Anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: Can you add your code that you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue like so:

```
v9.1/accounts' + `\(${acctId}\)`
```

I just needed to escape the parentheses ()